# Send Dropdownlist helper selected value to POST method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("pageSize",
      new SelectList(ViewBag.ListItems, "pageSize"), "pageSize",
      new
      {
            onchange = @"
            var form = document.forms[0];
            form.action='Home/Index';
            form.method='POST';
            form.submit();"
      })
```

based on the following ViewBag

```
ViewBag.ListItems = new List<Int16>
{
      5,
      20,
      50,
      100
};
```

All this placed over a html table in my Home Controller. I want to retrieve the amount of entries the user wants to see in my post method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? selectedOption, int? page, string pageSize)
{
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: amount of entries mean you want to retrieve how many times DropDownList value inserted into Db for a specific user?

Comment: Is the purpose of this for pagination of the table?

Comment: @ste-fu yes, it is to see if the user wants to paginate from 20 to 20, 50 to 50, and so on

Comment: I have put your code above into a new MVC project and it works fine? I did have to wrap your drop down in an empty <form> tag but it did work otherwise. what else is on the page? what issue are you actually seeing? in your solution is the "pageSize" param null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, pagignation should generally be dealt with via a Get request because of [idempotence](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html). Also it will cause fewer issues using the browser back button.

Assuming that your controller could look a little like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int pageNum = 1, int pageSize = 20)
{
    // Your pagination code here
}
```

In your view code, you don't need to put inline javascript (tends to be a bad idea anyway) You can put an id and/or a css class on the control to select it.

```
@Html.DropDownList("pageSize",
  new SelectList(ViewBag.ListItems, "pageSize"), "pageSize",
  new {@id="page-size", @class = "pager-control"})
```

Then in your javascript you could do something like this:

```
$(".pager-control").on("change", function(){
    window.location.replace(
        '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")' + '?pageNum=' + $("#page-num").val()
        + '&pageSize=' + $("#page-size").val());
    });
```

Note that this assumes your page control has an id of `"page-num"` and a class of `"pager-control"` as well. You can also choose whether to use replace or href depending on whether you want it in the browser history or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FormCollection to access dropdown.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form, int? page, string pageSize)
{
 string strDDLValue = form["pageSize"].ToString();
}
```